# How does ExactTarget decide record to send when sending to a Salesforce report with dedupe selected in the UIS?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Does anyone know how ExactTarget decides which lead or contact record to send when sending to a Salesforce report with dedupe selected in the UIS?

Thanks, Kevin

Comment: This is a great question - and I'm asking for some guidance here from our team.  No where does it explicitly say which, but my gut tells me the first one.

Comment: Thanks Kelly. When you say first once you're thinking the earliest created Lead or Contact with that email address? I'm going to do some tests too and will post here what I find, but it'd be great to know how it should work.

Comment: I've asked a few people, but haven't gotten a definitive. And yes, which ever lead/contact that is highest in the order - created date seems reasonable.

Comment: Hello Kelly, it'd be great if you can confirm this rather than my answering my own question. I ran some tests this evening sending to a report with multiple leads that had the same email address and the UIS in ExactTarget was set to de-dupe. Each time ExactTarget selected the most recently created lead record. I also tested modifying earlier records, but it didn't change the selection. So, from my test I would say ET de-dupes, selecting the most recently created Lead record. Can you confirm that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to respect the Report order. So It sends the first register that appears at Report.

Comment: Can you submit some papers or other methods to confirm this? How do you know that?

Comment: I do not have any paper, but you can do tests just by ordering your report at some field. Send one time ordering this field ascending and than send again ordering descending. You can see the Lead or the Contact Id at the tracking (the link next to "Total Sent") on ExactTraget and than compare with the Ids on your report.